# Will nginx route no traffic to an upstream host with weight 0?

Tags: nginx

I would like to temporarily route no traffic to a host in an nginx upstream. Rather than commenting it out, as this means nginx would be completely programmatically unaware of it, I was wondering whether setting its weight to zero would have the same effect (routing no traffic to the host). This is unclear from the documentation here http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#upstream

Will nginx honor `weight=0`?

Comment: Wouldnt just do it™ on a virtual machine suffice?

Comment: There is down flag

Comment: @Robus I noticed that there is no answer for this online, so I posted the question. Yes,  "just do it" would probably suffice, but an answer from someone who understands nginx internals would be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a (fairly cursory) reading of `ngx_http_upstream_get_peer` it seems nginx will pick a weight=0 server if there is nothing else to pick at all.

Specifically see https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/3fae83a91c6e5cda012adf6ee2783273e747f613/src/http/ngx_http_upstream_round_robin.c#L558

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to reload `nginx` with one upstream configured with weight=0 and it did not work.

Nginx said:

```
nginx: [emerg] invalid parameter "weight=0" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/upstream
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Comment: I suppose this behavior has changed since I asked the question, thank you for the note.

Answer (score 1):

As Alexey Ten said in the comment, you can use the `down` flag, e.g.:

```
upstream backend {
    ip_hash;

    server backend1.example.com;
    server backend2.example.com;
    server backend3.example.com down;
    server backend4.example.com;
}
```

https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#ip_hash